# display product information in the cart page

Tags: php, magento

I need to hide some payment methods for specific products. 
I tried a plugin but it did not work.

Now I am trying to display the product ID in the cart.phtml page. so i can use jquery to hide the payment. and i want to know how to display products ids in the cart.phtml?

Or if there is another and better way to achieve this result that will be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

EDIT::

```
<?php if($_item->getProductId() == 27){
    ?>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(".paypal-logo").hide();

    </script>
    <? } ?>
```

I am using the above code in default.phtml but it taking affect on the upper checkout button  and not the lower one.

Comment: Why are you putting the wrong payment methods onto the page for the products in the first place?

Comment: No what i am after is to prevent users from using paypal for specific product. And when activate it will show up for all product. you cant specify in magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I am trying to display the product ID in the cart.phtml page. so i
>   can use jquery to hide the payment. and i want to know how to display
>   products ids in the cart.phtml?

If that's how you want to do it:

Location of cart template files: app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/cart/

Location of cart line item files app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

Look for where you want to put the product id to go (let's assume after the product name).

Change this:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>
```

To this

`<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) . " " . $this->htmlEscape($this->getId())  ?>`

Edit:
If the above doesn't work also try $this->getProduct()->getId()  - depending on your version of Magento

Comment: thanks. but i want the id to be called from cart.phtml not default.phtml. as i need to hide the lower paypal button.

Comment: No you don't understand. You need to call it from items/default. 

Cart.phtml doesn't contain product specific information. checkout/cart/item/default.phtml is what calls the line item product specific information. So you have to call it in there. If you are using jQuery then it doesn't matter where you put your code because it will run on the browser side once the full page is loaded anyway. 
Did you clear your cache after making the changes?

Comment: Also are you using a different template to /default/default/ this would also change things... If so you need to change the path to:
app/design/frontend/[yourpackagename]/[yourthemename]/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

Comment: i added more explanation. to the post.

Comment: Your code won't work. Actually echo the product ID when you have multiple products in the cart and you'll find that you will only get 1 product id.

Comment: it worked. even if i had more than one product in my cart ;) thanks